Differences in fetch between git bash on windows and git on ubuntu
We are seeing a difference in git on windows and ubuntu when fetching from bitbucket.
On windows git bash 2.44.0 we see this. Pack size does not increase after each fetch
$ git fetch --tags --force --progress --depth=1 -- ssh://git@domain:7999/mob/solution.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

remote: Enumerating objects: 587, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (247/247), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (42/42), done.
remote: Total 67 (delta 26), reused 36 (delta 3), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (67/67), 10.38 KiB | 379.00 KiB/s, done.

On ubuntu git 2.44.0 we see this. Pack size increases after each fetch.
$ git fetch --tags --force --progress --depth=1 -- ssh://git@domain:7999/mob/solution.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

remote: Enumerating objects: 364276, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (263794/263794), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (86510/86510), done.
remote: Total 225273 (delta 170121), reused 168580 (delta 124035), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (225273/225273), 1.69 GiB | 26.58 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (170121/170121), completed with 12471 local objects.

Any ideas on what is happening?
Thanks
Tried different versions of git.
